# How to unit test asynchronous code made synchronous using CountdownLatch

Tags: java, unit-testing, service, callback

Below is the class I want to test :
**SomeClass.java**

```
public void SomeClass {

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    int result;
    registerCallbackWithService(new MyCallback());

    public int callToExternalService(){
        //Do some stuff and make service call
        latch.await();
        return result;
    }

    class MyCallback implements ServiceCallback {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final int res) {
            //do something
            result = res;
            latch.countdown();
        }
    }
}
```

The callback `MyCallback` was registered earlier before invoking `callToExternalService()`.
If I write a simple test to just mock the service call made in `callToExternalService()`, the test keeps on running infinitely because of `latch.await()`.
How can I test the logic in `callToExternalService()` as well as in `onResult()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified by code to expose the callback that I am registering using a package-protected function as below :

```
public void SomeClass {

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private int result;
    registerCallback(new MyCallback());

    public int callToExternalService(){
        //Do some stuff and make service call
        latch.await();
        return result;
    }

    private class MyCallback implements ServiceCallback {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final int res) {
            //do something
            result = res;
            latch.countdown();
        }
    }

    protected registerCallback(ServiceCallback callback) {
        registerCallbackWithService(callback);
    }
}
```

Now, for testing I do my testing by creating a new class `SomeClassTest extends SomeClass` and do my testing using an instance of this class. In `SomeClassTest` all I do is override `registerCallback()` to access the callback instance that is being registered.

```
public class ServiceTest {
    private ServiceCallback mServiceCallback;
    class SomeClassTest extends SomeClass {
        @Override
        registerCallback(ServiceCallback callback) {
            mServiceCallback = callback;
            super.registerCallback(callback);
        }
    }
}
```

Now all I have to do it using `doAnswer`, invoke the callback upon service request which results in the execution of `latch.countdown()` on the same `latch` reference that is put on `await` just after making the service request.

```
SomeClassTest someClassInstance = new SomeClassTest();
doAnswer(new Answer() {
            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
                mServiceVCallback.onResult(int_I_want_to_test_for)
                return null;
            }
        }).when(someClassInstance).service_request_before_latch_await();
int response = someClassInstance.callToExternalService();
assertEquals(response, expected_response);
```